# Pass a function argument like a regex variable for preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex

this is my function, i would like to pass the regex function argument to the preg_match_all function. It's possible to no write the regex again when i call the function ?

```
<?php

function extract_client($regex="#[^/home/](.+)[\W]#is",$string) {
    preg_match_all($regex, $string, $array);
    return print_r(rtrim($array[0][0] ,"/")); //the result should be "test"
}

extract_client($regex,"/home/test/abcd"); 

?>
```

Comment: how about: `extract_client("#[^/home/](.+)[\W]#is","/home/test/abcd"); ` ?

Comment: If you want to make a function parameter optional, the only way is to put it at the end: `function extract_client($string, $regex="#[^/home/](.+)[\W]#is")`. Then you can call it: `extract_client('this is my string');` or `extract_client('I like tomatoes', '~omat..~');`

Comment: it's is possible to set the regex one time , like a function argument  to avoid to add it every time i call the function?

Comment: why not just put it (the  regex ) inside the function  then?

Comment: @Dagon hahaha you'r right :P . Fixed thanks :)